# perl module for writing excel2007 workbook

Tags: perl, excel, cpan

I have a huge report coming out of a tool from which i extract the some important data and write a excel file. Till now i used the module Spreadsheet::WriteExcel, but it crashed when the number of rows exceed 65535. Is there any other module which supports generating excel for huge data? I checked in CPAN, found modules for reading excel2007 files but couldnt find one for writing. I am not writing a csv because, i want to generate multiple worksheets in the excel file.

Comment: Can't you convert it to CSV and parse it as a text file in Perl?

Comment: @Superfilin, I want to create different worksheets in the excel, thats the reason i am not writing a csv file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Excel-Writer-XLSX/) is an API compatible replacement for [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel/) that supports the Excel 2007 xlsx format and the increased row/column limits.

Comment: Thanks, it feels great to get answer directly from the develepor

Answer (score 3):

If you check the bugs [link](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Spreadsheet-WriteExcel) on the [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/) cpan site, you will notice there is an defect which is open for more than 11 months for this exact issue.

Bug ID: [54902](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=54902)

That said, can't you instead try writing in chunks of 65536 rows in each spreadsheet and later collate it?

Comment: Problem is number of rows is huge, it is in millions.